# State variables in Apex Batch - Do they have to be public or global?

Tags: apex, batch

Apex Batch classes by implementing the Database.Stateful interface can maintain state via the different Batch jobs. Just keept the state information in a member variable. The [example code from the docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) makes those variables global.

My question is, is that required or wouldn't it be better to keept them private?

```
global class SummarizeAccountTotal implements 
    Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{

   global final String Query;
   global integer Summary;

   global SummarizeAccountTotal(String q){Query=q;
     Summary = 0;
   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(
                Database.BatchableContext BC, 
                List<sObject> scope){
      for(sObject s : scope){
         Summary = Integer.valueOf(s.get('total__c'))+Summary;
      }
   }

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No they don't need to be global, like VF controllers any instance member (not marked as final, and presumably transient, though the docs are not clear) will be kept as state regardless of visibility.

Not only that but your classes and methods implementing interfaces no longer need to be 'global', this was since Summer'12 I believe. A welcome change in the way we have to implement system interfaces in my view. Unfortunately the documentation samples in Salesforce have not caught up.

Comment: I think instead of "final" you meant "transient"? Final members are still part of state even if they are final.

Comment: Actually both, the docs talk about final, but not transient, but I assume that works the same way. I'll update the answer a bit more.

Comment: Thats very good but I guess to late for all the global Batchable classes I have already out there. Is there any means to reduce the scope of already published classes besides replacing them with new ones?

Comment: Final members certainly make it to view state; while there would be an opportunity to optimize out final AND immutable members (e.g. Integer), VF does not appear to do that. Which docs are you referring to?

Comment: Hehe just realized you are probably talking about the Database.Stateful docs; I'm talking about VF View State. They almost certainly have different rules for state persistence.

Comment: @RobertS sadly i am not aware of any way to remove global methods. However you can deprecate them using the deprecated annotation. This prevents new subscribers to your package from seeing them at least. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_deprecated.htm